# When the glue rule fails, is it a given that $f(x)$ at a given point isn’t continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I’ve applied the glue rule to a question and found that $g(x)$, $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are not equal at $x=2$. Does this mean that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $2$ for definite or do I now need to prove this further by another rule?

The glue rule I have been taught has been defined as;

Let $f$ be defined on the open interval $I$ and let $a$ be a member of $I$. If there are functions $g$ and $h$ such that

1) $f(x) = g(x)$, $x \in I$, $x \lt$ a

2) $f(x)=h(x)$,$x \in I$,$x \gt$ a

3)$f(a) = g(a) = h(a) $

4) $g$ and $h$ are continuous at $a$.

Then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: What is the "glue rule"?

Comment: did you mean "Pasting lemma" ?

Comment: Please typeset your mathematics using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You need to put `$` signs around the math expressions for the formatting to take effect.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Have edited it to include what the glue rule is defined as!

Comment: @saulspatz Ahh thank you!! I’ll try that now!

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya It seems very similar to me! The function f is defined by the g and h which are two separated functions, one when x<2 and the other when x>2. I am trying to determine whether it is continuous at 2, does this sound like a question for the pasting Lemma?

Comment: @Becca that's pasting lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) and your answer is correct.